# Kendo grid tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to add a tooltip to a column in my grid using the code below. The tooltip shows but can't get the content to display. What could I be doing wrong?

```
function LoadStudents() {
var StudentGridColumns = [
    {
        title: 'StudentID',
        field: 'StudentID',
        hidden: true
    },
    {
        title: 'Student URL',
        field: 'StudentURL',
        template: function (rec) {
            return '<span>www...</span><img src="/images/qmark.jpg" data-tooltip="<a target=\'blank\' href=\'http://' + rec.StudentURL + '\'>' + rec.StudentURL + '</a>" />'
        }
    }
];

var StudentsGrid = $('#StudentGrid').data('kendoGrid');

$("#StudentGrid").kendoTooltip({
    filter: "img",
    position: "right",
    content: function (e) {
        var dataItem = $("#StudentGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(e.target.closest("tr"));
        var content = dataItem.Text;
        return content;
    }
  }).data("kendoTooltip");
}
```

Comment: Do you get some errors?

Comment: Yep. It says content is undefined

Comment: Questions: 1- Do you have a `Text` property in your dataSource? 2- Is your `dataSource` object been found(not undefined)? I'm asking because I could get it to work [in this demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/opOpA) just like you're trying.

Comment: That kind of questioning sent me in the right direction man. Thanks. Removing Text  and adding the correct property I got it working.